# Number input & validation

Tags: dialogflow-es

In my agent, user can write any number (8-12 digits) as a his first user input. For example, he writes: "111222333". I need to catch this digit-only input, validate it on my webhook and return a specific response/event.

I tried playing with @sys.any, as none of the system entities for number are not suitable. However, it is so greedy it also (correctly) catches characters. This means that such intent will actually serve as default fallback intent.

I tried playing with intent priorities, disabling Machine Learning for this intent, but no luck.

Anyone tried so solve similar issue in the past? Last resort I see is putting such validation between Dialogflow and user's channel on a dedicated server/cloud function, but I'd prefer to not do that.

Thanks!

P.S.: Suggestion to Dialogflow team to create @sys.any-digit sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build an Intent in my application to test your case.
I add some training phrases with a `number` parameter for the entity `@sys.number`.

[image]

After that I write in my assistant your number example : 111222333 and there the server response :

```
{
"originalRequest": {
    "source": "google",
    "version": "2",
    "data": {
        "isInSandbox": true,
        "surface": {
            "capabilities": [{
                "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            }, {
                "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
            }, {
                "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
            }, {
                "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
            }]
        },
        "inputs": [{
            "rawInputs": [{
                "query": "111222333",
                "inputType": "KEYBOARD"
            }],
            "arguments": [{
                "rawText": "111222333",
                "textValue": "111222333",
                "name": "text"
            }],
            "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
        }],
        "user": {
            "lastSeen": "2018-04-17T07:40:59Z",
            "locale": "fr-FR",
            "userId": "1522092989814"
        },
        "conversation": {
            "conversationId": "1523952140275",
            "type": "ACTIVE",
            "conversationToken": "[\"prenom-followup\"]"
        },
        "availableSurfaces": [{
            "capabilities": [{
                "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            }, {
                "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
            }]
        }]
    }
},
"id": "70c78adb-b14f-40c0-b766-e15e8a93445d",
"timestamp": "2018-04-17T08:07:09.807Z",
"lang": "fr-fr",
"result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "111222333",
    "speech": "",
    "action": "Prenom.Prenom-testNumber",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
        "number": "111222333"
    },
    "contexts": [{
        "name": "prenom-followup",
        "parameters": {
            "number": "111222333",
            "number.original": "111222333"
        },
        "lifespan": 1
    }, {
        "name": "actions_capability_screen_output",
        "parameters": {
            "number": "111222333",
            "number.original": "111222333"
        },
        "lifespan": 0
    }, {
        "name": "actions_capability_audio_output",
        "parameters": {
            "number": "111222333",
            "number.original": "111222333"
        },
        "lifespan": 0
    }, {
        "name": "google_assistant_input_type_keyboard",
        "parameters": {
            "number": "111222333",
            "number.original": "111222333"
        },
        "lifespan": 0
    }, {
        "name": "actions_capability_media_response_audio",
        "parameters": {
            "number": "111222333",
            "number.original": "111222333"
        },
        "lifespan": 0
    }, {
        "name": "actions_capability_web_browser",
        "parameters": {
            "number": "111222333",
            "number.original": "111222333"
        },
        "lifespan": 0
    }],
    "metadata": {
        "matchedParameters": [{
            "dataType": "@sys.number",
            "name": "number",
            "value": "$number",
            "isList": false
        }],
        "intentName": "Prenom - TestNumber",
        "isResponseToSlotfilling": false,
        "intentId": "22f80258-5673-4ffc-9f5e-93b4bc2df3f6",
        "webhookUsed": "true",
        "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
        "nluResponseTime": 56
    },
    "fulfillment": {
        "speech": "",
        "messages": [{
            "type": 0,
            "speech": ""
        }]
    },
    "score": 1.0
},
"status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
},
"sessionId": "1523952140275"
}
```

The JSON response has two parts : `originalRequest` with the user entrance `111222333` and the `result` where you can get and catch the final number on your webhook function :

- ["result"]["parameters"]["number"] = 111222333

For remember [here the documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities) of `Dialogflow system-entities`.

Comment: Hi Jordan, many thanks! Unfortunately, this doesn't work for other numbers, e.g.: "9995554443", "000111222333444555", as Dialogflow will not serve it as a parameter. However, it led me to another idea of creating a regular expression on my webhook and doing the validation there. Hence, accepted -- many thanks!

Comment: this doesn't work with voice either. When you speak a number the voice split it with a space after 4th digit. For e.g. `12345678` when spoken it is taken as `1234 5678`

Comment: @AnkurArora maybe try `@sys.phone-number` instead of `@sys.number` for phone number.